# `cat: /srv/buildd/buildlist-debian-minimal: No such file or directory` when running xbuilder

Tags: command-line

When I run programs I get errors like this

```
$ xbuilder
cat: /srv/buildd/buildlist-debian-minimal: No such file or directory
```

How can I get the missing files?

Comment: what program are you trying to run and how?

Comment: xbuilder and it also show this error for another files when i use different programs. i just want a solution how to get these missing files.

Comment: the solution is different in each case. In this case, it seems like the program is not installed in the way its startup script/process expects...

Comment: then how can i do this with terminal?

Comment: I have no idea. I don't know xbuilder. Perhaps someone will know. Did you do something previously that might have messed up your system?

Comment: is it possible to download these files with just commands?

Comment: You can run `dpkg -S /path/to/file` to see which package provides the file and install or reinstall the package, if the package/file is in dpkg database

Comment: rohit@rohit-Vostro-15-3568:~$ dpkg -S /srv/buildd/buildlist-debian-minimal
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /srv/buildd/buildlist-debian-minimal

Comment: now this error.........

Comment: that's not an error, it just means `dpkg` doesn't know where that file should have come from. I knew that already, I was just saying, that's the generic way. I don't know what you can do in this case :(

Comment: How did you install `xbuilder`? There are several programs with that name.